# Internal Server Error after pushing django project to Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment, uwsgi

I'm trying to deploy to Heroku my django project. However, after pushing to Heroku, I'm seeing an "internal server error" though locally it works correctly.

**heroku logs:**

```
ImportError: No module named app.wsgi
  --- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
 --- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=645f6570-112d-46d9-9578-1b4e90c4b7d9 fwd="5.144.57.6" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=500 bytes=104
```

My **uwsgi** configuration looks like:

```
[uwsgi]
print = Hello I'm the uWSGI config for %c project!

;uid = user
;gid = staff
;chmod-socket = 664
;chown-socket = user:staff

auto-procname
protocol = uwsgi
procname-prefix-spaced = [uWSGI %c]
socket = %d%c.sock
http-socket = :$(PORT)
master
processes = %k
autoload
no-orphans
die-on-term
memory-report
disable-logging
ignore-write-errors
ignore-sigpipe
enable-threads
single-interpreter
lazy-apps
vacuum

harakiri = 60
harakiri-verbose
reload-mercy = %k
worker-reload-mercy = %k
max-requests = 5000
buffer-size = 65535
post-buffering = 1048576
reload-on-rss = 300
touch-reload = %p

;for-readline = .env
;  env = %(_)
;end-for

pp = %d

module = %c.wsgi

;[stats]
;stats = %d%c.stats.sock
;stats = :1717

; serving static files via uwsgi
static-map2 = /assets=%dpublic
static-map2 = /uploads=%dpublic


;[cache]
cache = 1000
cache-blocksize = 65536

;[prdoduction]
if-env = DEV=False
print = Loaded production settings!
disable-logging
ignore-write-errors
ignore-sigpipe
endif

;[development]
if-env = DEV=True
print = Loaded development settings!
venv = /Users/user/.virtualenvs/%c
;logto = %dlogs/%c.uwsgi.log
py-autoreload = 2
endif
```

Comment: How do you structure your project and what does your `Procfile` look like?

Comment: Procfile: `web: uwsgi uwsgi.ini` and `uwsgi` outside others apps

Comment: The information you provided is insufficient; your Profile includes an `ini` file, you should edit your post to include how you set up your `uwsgi`

Comment: I would start with a simpler configuration and start adding in options once you've got the basic configuration working. For a basic configuration that I can confirm works, see the configuraiton in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27571641/how-to-optimize-uwsgi-for-heroku-routers-proxy-buffering-situation

Comment: I have a question, which doesn't answer your question: how did you decide to use some of the values you ended up using? For example, post-buffering & buffer-size & reload-on-rss... what made you decide to go with the values you went with? I feel like the uWSGI documentation is fairly sparse on helping someone that isn't a web server expert know what/why to use some of the different configuration options.