# How to optimize uWSGI for Heroku routers' proxy/buffering situation?

Tags: python, heroku, uwsgi

I've been using uWSGI in production on heroku for over a year, and it seems to handle everything a lot better than Gunicorn. As our traffic scales up, I am trying to better understand the interface between heroku's router and uWSGI in order to optimize and prevent problems, but its all still pretty opaque to me and I have a few questions.

Right now, I'm using a fairly vanilla uwsgi configuration:

```
#heroku setup: see https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi-docs/blob/master/tutorials/heroku_python.rst
http-socket = :$(PORT)
master = true
die-on-term = true
harakiri = 20
harakiri-verbose
reload-mercy = 8
max-requests = 2000
# processes = 5 # set from env var WEB_CONCURRENCY ( see Procfile)
# the below is required by new relic. be sure to monitor your system
# memory since we're enabling threads
# https://newrelic.com/docs/python/python-agent-and-uwsgi
# http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html
enable-threads = true
single-interpreter = true

# the module
module = publisher.wsgi
```

Reading Heroku's documentation, it sounds like the heroku proxy does several somewhat unique things, and I'm wondering if I need to do anything special to uWSGI to optimize for this environment. For example

1) [Heroku will send 50 requests to the dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#request-queueing) (i.e. to uwsgi) simultaneously before it starts queuing them

2) Heroku has its [own flavor of request buffering](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#request-buffering) that may or may not affect uwsgi.

I specifically wonder whether I should turn on [post-buffering](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#post-buffering), adjust the [buffer-size](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#buffer-size), or tweak any other of the many uWSGI settings for better performance or to prevent problems when running behind the Heroku router.

Comment: Hey Ben, it's been a year since you posted this and I am wondering if you have any new insight into questions you posted?